The date title doesn't display in day views when groupByDateAndResource is true
I'm using fullcalendar v3. I don't know why the Date title is hidden in the Day view when I set groupByDateAndResource to true. In other views it still displays.
How can I display the title in the day view when groupByDateAndResource is true?
{
  type: type,
  columnFormat: this.getColumnFormatByLocale(),
  duration: { days: duration },
  groupByDateAndResource: true,
  refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true
};


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you please provide a [mre] of this issue? As far as I can see, groupByDateAndResource works perfectly fine in all of the agenda views - here's a demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bGPRJqj?editors=001 . Can you [edit] your question to include enough code and data so that it would demonstrate the problem you're having in your environment? That way maybe we can see what's wrong and be able to help you. Thanks.

P.S. Of course if the view is only 1 day long it's natural to hide the date row in the table, because the same date is shown in the header anyway, so it would be identical. That is the expected behaviour, not a bug.

As you said "It's normal behavior, not a bug". But my customer wants to see the Date on the work calendar instead of reviewing it on the calendar. Can I customize to show Date title?

my customer wants to see...but why? All they have to do is look 1cm above on the screen and they will see the date anyway (reference: https://imgur.com/a/x5ChCcH). Yes you could probably customise it but you would have to understand and modify the internal code of fullCalendar, or create your own custom view type. Neither of these is a simple or quick process, and there is no real benefit, because you would just be showing the same data which is already easily visible on the screen. If I was you I would be suggesting to your customer that it's not worth the time or cost to customise it.

Also bear in mind that fullcalendar 3 is obsolete (right now the latest version is 6, and its internals are very different), so any customisation of that will have even less value or longevity
